# publish message feed to facebook page wall in javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, message, publish

Good day:
I've created a function javascript that post a feed on my facebook page using a facebook app.
I'm the administrator of a page and of a facebook app.
I used FB.getLoginStatus function with "publish_actions,publish_pages,manage_pages" scope
This is the api calls FB.api("/" + pageId + "/feed", "post", {message: 'test message', access_token: accessToken});
The access token is of the page.
When I execute it, any post are published on a page.
If I read a response by log console (including function (response) on a method) the post id appears, but nothing is in the page.
I've tried to search this id in facebook but not is found.
If I try to publish photos or albums in the same page with the same app and javascript function and access tokeb, all run correctly.
I tested it running my script and using Graph API Explorer (setting my facebook app and the page access token), but with the same result.
How can I resolve the problem?

Comment: is your app public? (app review tab in the app settings)

Comment: Yes. Infact I can publish photos, albums on the page and all on my personal wall.

Comment: The strange thing is that if I get all posts or one single id post that I don't see on the page, I obtain it.
I've just tried to publish a post with Graph Api Explorer using it instead of my facebook app I view the feed on the page.

Comment: on your personal wall? use a page access token then, i guess you are using a user access token.

Comment: No, on my personal wall I use user access token and in the page wall I use page access token.